# Remove all GUI elements from a Firefox 29 window under a specific profile

Tags: linux, firefox, linux-mint

I'd like to make desktop shortcuts to certain webapps to a Firefox 29 window w/ all the GUI elements such as tabs, menubar, buttons, etc. removed. I'm following [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137235/why-is-firefox-prism-not-in-the-repositories-anymore/137381#137381) instructions.

This screengrab sums up what I'd like to do:

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but the simplest way for a novice is to use extensions. The two below will remove both the tab bar and the address bar.

- [Hide Tab Bar with One Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-tab-bar-with-one-tab/)
- [Hide Navigation Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/hide-navigation-bar/)

Install these in the appropriate profile, and peruse the options to make sure they are enabled.

A more advanced way that is easy to copy to multiple profiles is to edit the userchrome.css file. Open your new profile's folder, then create a folder called "chrome." Create a file in that folder called "userchrome.css." In a text editor, add the following lines.

```
@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");
#navigator-toolbox { display: none }
```

Feel free to copy the chrome folder to any other profile folder.

### NOTE

Both of these options may result in losing the titlebar. To be safe, before enabling them, go to about:config and search for browser.tabs.drawInTitlebar, and set that preference to false.

Comment: A very well thought out and complete answer. I'll try this tomorrow before I mark it as the answer thanks very much for your help!